# Spring Boot download speed test very slow on localhost

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I wrote a very basic speed test with a Spring Boot application and a NodeJS application. My NodeJS goes up to 2.2Gbps whereas my Spring Boot app goes up to at most 550 Mbps. I tried two different implementations in Spring Boot which both produce relatively the same speeds.

**Implementation 1:** (up to 550 Mbps)

```
private long downloadDuration = 10000;
private int downloadChunkSize = 1024 * 1024;

@GetMapping("/test")
public void downloadTest(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    OutputStream os = response.getOutputStream();
    final byte[] bytes = getRandomChunk();
    long endOn = System.currentTimeMillis() + downloadDuration;

    while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endOn) {
        os.write(bytes, 0, downloadChunkSize);
    }

    os.close();
}
```

**Implementation 2** (up to 500 Mbps)

```
@GetMapping("/test2")
public StreamingResponseBody downloadTest2() {

    final byte[] bytes = getRandomChunk();
    final long endOn = System.currentTimeMillis() + downloadDuration;

    return new StreamingResponseBody() {
        @Override
        public void writeTo(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
            while (System.currentTimeMillis() <= endOn) {
                out.write(bytes);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Using NodeJS an `XHRRequest`, I can reach 2.2 Gpbs easily.

Any idea what I am doing wrong ?

For the reference:

```
private byte[] getRandomChunk() {
    final byte[] bytes = new byte[1024 * 1024];
    ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextBytes(bytes);
    return bytes;
}
```

And the NodeJS code:

```
const requestHandler = (request, response) => {
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    const startTime = new Date();
    const endOn = new Date(startTime.getTime() + 10000);
    const chunkSize = 1024 * 1024;

    const chunk = 'a'.repeat(chunkSize);

    const sendNext = () => {
        response.write(chunk, undefined, () => {
            if (new Date() <= endOn) {
                sendNext();
            } else {
                response.end();
            }
        });
    };

    sendNext();
};

const testServer = http.createServer(requestHandler);
```

And here is a minimal working example for the front-end speed test:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>
<body>

<div id="speed" style="font-size: 41px;">0 Mbps</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const url = 'http://localhost:3001';

    const nThreads = 4;
    const method = 'GET';

    const speedLabel = document.getElementById('speed');

    let totalDownloaded = 0;
    let mainStart;
    let totalElapsed = 0;

    function download(i) {

        let downloaded = 0;

        const dl = new XMLHttpRequest();

        dl.onload = function (e) {
            console.log('[%d] Done', i);
            dl.abort(); // Done, Empty RAM
        };

        dl.onprogress = function (e) {
            const previousDownloaded = downloaded;
            downloaded = e.loaded;

            // Update global variables
            totalDownloaded += downloaded - previousDownloaded;
            totalElapsed = (performance.now() - mainStart) / 1000;
            totalSpeed = 8 * (totalDownloaded / 1000000) / totalElapsed;

            // Update UI
            speedLabel.innerHTML = (totalSpeed) + ' Mbps';
        };

        dl.open(method, url + '?threadId=' + i + '&nocache=' + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000000000));
        dl.send();
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        mainStart = performance.now();
        for (let i = 0; i < nThreads; i++) {
            download(i);
        }
    };
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try removing `flush()`. Don't know why you even added that.

Comment: @Andreas I'm surprised he got 550M with a per-byte flush.

Comment: @chrylis Well, not a per-byte flush, OP is writing blocks of `downloadChunkSize` bytes, whatever number that is.

Comment: *FYI:* Calling `response.setStatus(200);` *after* writing full content has no effect, because the headers have already been written at that point. Move that statement up next to the `setHeader` calls. --- Also, why use `addHeader`, not `setHeader`, with the `Content-Type` header? You cannot have multiple `Content-Type` headers. Change that to `setHeader`.

Comment: @Andreas `downloadChunkSize` is `1024 * 1024`, sorry for not providing the information in the example. I removed the `.flush()` but I still can't go higher than 600Mbps. I just updated the code. I'm using a clean project, just generated a few minutes ago from starter.spring.io.

Comment: What webapp server are you running? Tomcat? If so, are you using the default (slower) connectors, or did you enable the faster *native* connectors? If not, perhaps you should research how to do that, e.g. read [Apache Portable Runtime (APR) based Native library for Tomcat](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/apr.html)

Comment: I'm using Tomcat with the default connector. I didn't know there were faster connectors you could enable. But honestly, even with the starter application, I should be able to get up to 1Gbps without any issue on localhost :/ Also, swapping the chunk size of 1MB for 1kB doesn't change anything really.

Comment: What does your Node code look like?

Comment: @AndyWilkinson juste updated my post with the code you asked for :)

Comment: Your Node code and Java code aren't equivalent. It's going to take longer to generate 1MB of random bytes than it is to create 1MB of `a` characters.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson yes, but this doesn't really matter as the test lasts 10 seconds. The generation is only once for the whole test, not at each round.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson Nevermind, you're the man !!!!!!!!! Remove the `ThreadLocalReadom`... fixes the problem. However, I don't understand why this line slows the download down as the array is only initialized once.

Comment: @Andreas I was testing a cycle involving 4 systems and a few requests and, by replacing the NIO connectors with APR connectors (and by moving SSL handling from Tomcat to NGINX), I managed to decrease the total time from `4.594 s` to `4.151 s`/`4.203 s`.